# Updating integer column with null values in postgres

Tags: postgresql, null, sql-update, alter

I would like to update my column with other column in other table. Before doing so, I would like to nullify my column(integer) first. However, below code did not work. (column_a: bigint; column_b: text)

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET column_a IS NULL
WHERE column_b = 'XXX';
```

ERROR: syntax error at or near "ISNULL"

Comment: Got an answer. For integer column, this should be "= null"

Answer (score 164, accepted):

This should be,

```sql
UPDATE table1 
SET column_a = NULL
WHERE column_b = 'XXX';
```

Comment: can you somehow do that from the table view? Like with mySql Workbench you right click a field and there's a set to null option there. Never mind me you can just delete the value from a field and it will set it to null.